# How to setCustomView of actionbarsherlock in SherlockFragmentActivity class

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I am using SherlockFragmentActivity as my main activity class. below is the code...

```
 public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{
  protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar ab = getSherlock().getActionBar();
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View customView = li.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_layout, null);
    customView.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ,ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    ab.setCustomView(customView);
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);}  }
```

I have also tried with

```
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customView);
```

and this is my my_custom_layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/light_gradient" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text="Settings" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:text="Home"/></RelativeLayout>
```

I have defined my activity in manifest file as below

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.demo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos.EXAMPLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now my problem is that I am not able to set custom view of my actiobar. can any one help me.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "not able"...? What happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: my mean to say is that default action bar appears instead of my custom layout action bar.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to enable showing the custom view. Try adding `ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)`.

Comment: please post your answer instead of comment. I will mark it as best answer.

Comment: Glad to hear! The same suggestion was also made by @kettu, so feel free to tick his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
 View mView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT, null);
 ActionBar ab=getSupportActionBar();
 ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
 ab.setCustomView(mView);
```

Answer (score 2):

use this...

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

Comment: This worked for me on Android 2.3 AND 4+, but NOT the accepted answer. The accepted answer did work fine for Android 4+ though.

Note, you will not get the home button with this solution -- if needed use `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);`